# Get count of group-level observations with multiple individual observations from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I get a dataframe like this:

```
soccer_player country position
"sam"         USA     left defender
"jon"         USA     right defender
"sam"         USA     left midfielder
"jon"         USA     offender
"bob"         England goalie
"julie"       England central midfielder
"jane"        England goalie
```

To look like this (country with the counts of unique players per country):

```
country player_count
USA     2
England 3
```

The obvious complication is that there are multiple observations per player, so I cannot simply do `table(df$country)` to get the number of observations per country.

I have been playing with the `table()` and `merge()` functions but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
as.data.frame(table(unique(d[-3])$country))
#      Var1 Freq
# 1 England    3
# 2     USA    2
```

Drop the third column, remove any duplicate Country-Name pairs, then count the occurrences of each country.

Comment: Position is not guaranteed to be unique. Trying out in R right now, but not sure this would work.

Comment: This doesn't assume that.

Comment: Okay, thanks Matthew. I'm going to play around with it, and given the succinctness of this method if it works, will mark as answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: Better title suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

The [new features of dplyr v 3.0](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/10/13/dplyr-0-3-2/) provide a compact solution:

Data:

```
dd <- read.csv(text='
soccer_player,country,position
"sam",USA,left defender
"jon",USA,right defender
"sam",USA,left midfielder
"jon",USA,offender
"bob",England,goalie
"julie",England,central midfielder
"jane",England,goalie')
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% distinct(soccer_player,country) %>% 
       count(country)
```

Answer (score 6):

Without using any packages you can do:

```
List = by(df, df$country, function(x) length(unique(x$soccer_player)))
DataFrame = do.call(rbind, lapply(names(List), function(x) 
  data.frame(country=x, player_count=List[[x]])))
#  country player_count
#1 England            2
#2     USA            2
```

It's easier with something like `data.table`:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,list(player_count = length(unique(soccer_player))),by=country]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an sqldf solution:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select country, count(distinct soccer_player) player_count 
       from df 
       group by country")

##   country player_count
## 1 England            2
## 2     USA            2
```

and here is a base R solution:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(~ country, unique(df[1:2])), responseName = "player_count")

##   country player_count
## 1 England            2
## 2     USA            2
```

Answer (score 1):

One more base R option, using `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(soccer_player ~ country, dd, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
#  country soccer_player
#1 England             3
#2     USA             2
```